# How to create loops using processing algorithm in python console from QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm new with python programming and I need some help for my case.
I want to use inverse distance weighted function to interpolate precipitation values using values from 78 weather stations. so I create this sequence of processing algorithms that run perfectly one time and produce an interpolate raster layer as I wantedbold.
The problem is that I wanted to run these sequence all the times I need. All bold "9" values in code should be run to numbers 2, 3, 4 ..., 10, including number 10.
Any ideas for helping me?

```
processing.runalg("qgis:joinattributestable", "D:\PATRICIA\IG\QGIS\DIST_COSTA_etrs89.shp", "D:\PATRICIA\DOCUMENTOS\ESTACOES METEOROLOGICAS\DADOS METEOROLOGICOS\HR\H_1999_1_**9**.xlsx", "EST", "num", "D:\PATRICIA\IG\QGIS\FWI\HR\ETACOES_HR_1999_1_**9**")
processing.runalg("qgis:selectbyattribute", "D:\PATRICIA\IG\QGIS\FWI\HR\ETACOES_HR_1999_1_**9**.shp", "H", 1, "NULL", "D:\PATRICIA\IG\QGIS\FWI\HR\ETACOES_HR_1999_1_**9**.shp")
processing.runalg("qgis:saveselectedfeatures", "D:\PATRICIA\IG\QGIS\FWI\HR\ETACOES_HR_1999_1_**9**.shp", "D:\PATRICIA\IG\QGIS\FWI\HR\ESTACOES_HR_1999_1_**9**_SF_Int.shp")
processing.runalg("qgis:selectbyattribute", "D:\PATRICIA\IG\QGIS\FWI\HR\ESTACOES_HR_1999_1_**9**_SF_Int.shp", "H", 1, "-999.9", "D:\PATRICIA\IG\QGIS\FWI\HR\ESTACOES_HR_1999_1_**9**_SF_Int.shp")
processing.runalg("qgis:saveselectedfeatures", "D:\PATRICIA\IG\QGIS\FWI\HR\ESTACOES_HR_1999_1_**9**_SF_Int.shp", "D:\PATRICIA\IG\QGIS\FWI\HR\ESTACOES_HR_1999_1_**9**_SF.shp")
processing.runalg("saga:inversedistanceweighted", "D:\PATRICIA\IG\QGIS\FWI\HR\ESTACOES_HR_1999_1_**9**_SF.shp", "H", 0, 2, 0, 1, 100, 0, 0, 8, "-152444.0, 180000.0, -302911.0, 280000.0", 100, "D:\PATRICIA\IG\QGIS\FWI\HR\Python_HR_Viz8_Cell100_**9**")
```

Comment: I see by your file path syntax that you're not running in linux which is a shame. If you were, you could run batches of processing.runalg commands in parallel as described in http://www.purplelinux.co.nz/?p=190

Answer (score 3):

Write a for loop and use string replacement to replace the "bold 9" with the current value of i, as in

`for i in range(2,11):
    path = "D:\PATRICIA\IG\QGIS\FWI\HR\ETACOES_HR_1999_1_%d" %(i)`

Comment: @PatríciaFernandes please upvote helpful answers and accept answers which solve your problem by clicking the tick mark on the left side of the answer.